# Spark structured streaming watermark with OutputMode.Complete

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I wrote simple query which should ignore data where created < last event time - 5 seconds. But this query doesn't work. All data is printed out.

Also I tried to use window function `window($"created", "10 seconds", "10 seconds")`, but that didn't help.

```
val inputStream = new MemoryStream[(Timestamp, String)](1, spark.sqlContext)

val df = inputStream.toDS().toDF("created", "animal")

val query = df
  .withWatermark("created", "5 seconds")
  .groupBy($"animal")
  .count()
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
  .start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more grouping by info like such:

```
val windowedCounts = words
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
    .groupBy(
        window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
        $"word")
    .count()
```

Moreover, from the manual:

Output mode must be Append or Update. Complete mode requires all aggregate data to be preserved, and hence **cannot** use watermarking to drop intermediate state.